# How to stop elements resizing when I change the zoom on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a newbie to HTML and CSS, facing a problem where when I resize my page, the elements go berserk. I've tried everything from creating a main wrapper and adding max widths and heights, but all to no avail. Here is my code in CSS so that you can take a look.

```
body {
  background-image: url(3eMAHaa.jpg)
}

div.header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 26%;
  padding-bottom: 26%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%
}

h1 {
  ;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 40%;
  color: #FF2B24;
  font-family: helvetica
}

.someimage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 32%
}

div.navbox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  padding-left: 500px;
  padding-right: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  right: 2%
}

img.about {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 80%;
  top: 35%
}


}
img.location {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: absolute
}
img.contact {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  top: 35%
}
```

Comment: Which element u want to stop resizing?

Comment: The three image links (About, location, contact) and the DIV navigation box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys, figured it out. I had to set a a bigger DIV as a parent and then change all the other elements to relative positioning so they wouldn't move about. It was a hassle, but it worked! :). Also, try to use pixels instead of % as percentages aren't fixed values and will cause stuff to go crazy when you zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your all padding code then it will not be resized

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: When I remove the padding code I can't see the outline of the DIV :(